# Function inside Task.Run doesn't get executed

Tags: .net-core, async-await, task, task-parallel-library, fire-and-forget

I have some slow part of my code that does a http request then waits for the answer and calls an adf pipeline so it can update a database parameter at the end. Since this took 2 minutes and my client app seemed so slow for my clients, I wrapped this call inside `Task.Run()` and set my logic inside. This works good but the last part, update a database parameter, doesn't get executed at all.

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await client.ExecuteAsync(request, CancellationToken.None);
    await RunADFPipeline(pipeline, _config);
    await _projectRepository.UpdateValue(id, "status", "unlock");
});
```

I found this example online and I applied it in my code. The first two awaits seem to execute correctly but the third one doesn't execute at all. If I set it outside of `Task.Run()`, it executes. The third part literally just calls a stored procedure

```
return await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("EXEC core.UpdateValue @ProjectId, @Name, @Value", parameters);
```

I also tried by adding `ContinueWith()` at the end of the `Task.Run()` but still no luck.

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await client.ExecuteAsync(request, CancellationToken.None);
    await _adfHelper.RunADFPipeline(pipeline, _config);
}).ContinueWith((result) => _projectRepository.UpdateValue(id, "status", "unlock"));
```

All this code is inside a controller. Any thoughts and ideas on how can I achieve my goal and update this parameter after `Task.Run()` finishes or the functions inside finish?

Comment: Why are you running asynchronous operations inside `Task.Run` ? And why aren't you awaiting `Task.Run` itself? If you use DI to inject `_projectRepository` as a scoped service, it will get disposed as soon as the action completes. If you don't await `Task.Run` the repo itself will get disposed before the method has a chance to start running

Comment: If I await it, I have to wait for it 2 minutes and it slows my client app (or it makes it so). I found this as a fire-and-forget way online.. What do you suggest, how can I improve it?

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway and why aren't you calling those methods directly in the action? Each request is handled by a separate thread so there's no need to use extra threads/tasks in a web app, unless you want to execute some methods concurrently. If you want to start a long running job on the other hand, you can't just use a Task or thread. You'll have to use a BackgroundService at least. Check [Background tasks with Hosted Services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: `I found this as a fire-and-forget way online.` It's not. It doesn't work in most cases, certainly not in web apps. At the very least use a BackgroundService. A better option would be to use a scheduling library like Hangfire, Coravel or Quartz.net, which would allow you to define jobs as methods or classes, schedule them or start them manually, and monitor them

Comment: I'm not calling them because I want them to execute in the background but still to await on each other while executing in the background. So you suggest me to use BackgroundService and try it that way?